# ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)Unhandled Exception:PlatformException(failed_to_fetch_sms, Flutter Telephony: Error getting SmsManager

Tags: android, flutter, dart, telephony

I have never used telephony. I first set up a package and wrote the codes as a pub dev example, but when I send sms after requesting and getting sms permission, it shows this error:
`[ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(failed_to_fetch_sms, Flutter Telephony: Error getting SmsManager, null, null)`

My code here:

```
   await Telephony.instance.sendSms(
                to: controller1.text,
                message: controller2.text
               );
```

Comment: could you help?

Comment: Can you please add the code that shows how you're sending the SMS?

Comment: I added part of my code that sends sms

Comment: Are you requesting the SMS permission in the Android Manifest file?

Comment: Of course I added sms permission in the Android Manifest

Comment: TarHalda, any solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is from https://github.com/shounakmulay/Telephony/issues/149

You can temporarily use package from my repository by changing telephony package inside pubspec.yaml

telephony:
git:
url: https://github.com/suhardik/s_telephony.git
ref: develop